# FOL formula transformation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have the following predicates:

- President(P)
- Age(P)

Is this FOL formula transformation correct? I'm a little unsure.

**The minimum age of the president is 25 years old.**

$$ ∀P[\text{President}(P) ⇒ \text{Age}(P) \ge 25] $$

Comment: Are you sure that $Age(x)$  is a predicate? A predicate of the form $P(x)$ says that $x$ has the property $P$. For example, "$Age(x) \geq 25$"  is a predicate, not $Age(x)$.

Comment: Yes, the first predicate is decribed as "P is the president" and the second one is "The age of P"